# Getting JSON data into Firebase via an external URL

Tags: json, api, rest, firebase

First time I have looked at Firebase, I need to import some JSON data into Firebase and then check/retrieve data from this URL every 3 minutes.

Is this possible and how can I go about automatic imports of data into Firebase?